# Kotlin: Sinus generator (beat) 2 individual sinus (rectange, triangle) frequencies shall generate a beat and output via BlueTooth

Tags: kotlin, audio, playback

today I want to try my second app.
I want to program a app where you can input 2 different frequencies and the app generates a beat from these frequencies.
This beat I want to output via Bluetooth.
I want to output the beat as long as I will stop it by pressing a button or similar.

I just have this code:

```
 fun playSinusTone(frequency: Int, duration: Int) {
            val sampleRate = 44100
            val numSamples = duration * sampleRate
            val buffer = ShortArray(numSamples)

            val angularFrequency = 2 * PI * frequency.toDouble()

            for (i in 0 until numSamples) {
                val sample = (sin(angularFrequency * i / sampleRate) * Short.MAX_VALUE)
                buffer[i] = sample.toInt().toShort()
            }

            val audioTrack = AudioTrack(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                numSamples * 2,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC
            )

            audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, numSamples)
            audioTrack.play()
        }
```

But the "AudioTrack" is not a valid function any more obviously (deprecated). It is crossed out. What shall I use instead?
One issue I have with this function anyway. I want to play a sinus tone and stop it by pressing a switch. So this AudioTrack does not have the possibility to play the tone endlessly.

What is the best way to program this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation of the libraries you are using, specifically the documentation of the "AudioTrack" "function"?  (it is a class btw, and it is not deprecated, that particular constructor is)

Comment: Now I found a code @github: https://rajat-r-bapuri.github.io/DSP-Lab-Android-Demos/Android_Demos/kotlin_implementations/Sine_Wave_Demo1/

Comment: but how to add a second sine wave?

Comment: The code should be able to output 2 sinus waves to the same time, if this is possible. Or is it not possible with AudioTrack? I tried it but I have a distortion, disturbance like a crack or similar in the loudspeaker. Can this be avoided?

Comment: I now found out that TarsosDSP could be a solution.

Comment: but I have the issue that I cannot import the classes: import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioDispatcher
import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioEvent
import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioProcessor
import be.tarsos.dsp.io.jvm.JVMAudioInputStream
import be.tarsos.dsp.io.jvm.JVMAudioInputStreamFactory
import be.tarsos.dsp.synthesis.SineGenerator
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing.JFrame
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
import java.awt.event.ActionListener

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: I would suggest creating a question on that specific issue. There are multiple tutorials on SO on how to ask a question "properly". That way you will get the exposure you need from the people that are able to help you.

Comment: yes I know. My asking was confusing. I will try to find a proper tutorial.